# Is it possible to use smarty functions outside the smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

If in a php file you had:

```
$smarty->assign('content','<p>This is some test content</p>');
```

and in a template file I hadb (just for example purposes):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>{$content}{config_load file='settings.conf'}{#setting1#}</body>
</html>
```

Would it be possible to load the setting from the config file, from the php file instead of the template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a config file with [config_load()](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.config.load.php) and then use [get_config_Vars()](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.get.config.vars.php) to obtain a loaded value.

Comment: Thanks muchly. I'm assuming then most smarty functions can be called outside the template if for example {function_name} would just be as simple as $smarty->function_name() in the php file.